# How to I prevent nick changing involuntarily?

Tags: irc, xchat

I use `XChat` on `Ubuntu 12.04`.

I have been facing this issue:

1. I join a channel.
2. I minimize XChat and do other work. If someone pings me on IRC I respond.
3. After some time I come back to XChat to see that my nick has changed.

**Why?**

XChat indicates that I have been disconnected. (Probably because the connection got weak, but I'm not sure)

A fresh connection has been tried with my old nick.

**But my old nick still exists in the channel.**(why?)

So, I get my second nick choice. This changes my nick.

This has been annoying me.

What can I do about it?

Comment: In addition to @AaronMiller's answer (which I think should be a *proper answer* and not a comment btw), I'd add, consider using a dedicated server with a stable Internet connection, and some kind of client/server IRC client: either Quassel or Smuxi. The dedicated server will keep your IRC connection active.

Comment: @allquixotic Comment converted to answer.

Comment: @allquixotic: What do you mean by a dedicated server? I mostly chat on `Freenode` server. I don't have a choice because that is where the channel is. Is using `Quassel` better than `XChat`? Thanks.

Comment: @learner You know -- a *dedicated server*. That means a box in a datacenter somewhere that you rent out. Of course by "dedicated server" I also mean things like a virtual private server (which is a special case of a dedicated server that runs as a virtual machine on a dedicated server), or similar. Google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to ensure that you keep your nick across connections, and that no one else can grab it out from under you, is to register it with the NickServ bot on your IRC server, and then authenticate to NickServ when you log in.

To register your nick, which needs doing only once, you'd:

```
/msg nickserv register [nick] [password]
```

Thereafter, when logging in, do:

```
/nick [nick]
/msg nickserv identify [password]
```

(If you don't identify to NickServ within a short time after setting your nick, it will automatically change your nick to something else, as it doesn't know you're the one who registered that nick until you tell it so with the `identify` command.)

When logging on after forcible disconnection, as in the case which prompted your question, you can have NickServ clean up your previous connection so that you can reclaim your nick, and this is done as:

```
/msg nickserv ghost [nick] [password]
/nick [nick]
```

(You may or may not need to `identify` after the `/nick` command here; I tend to think not, since you've just implicitly done so in the `ghost` command, but IIRC different NickServ instances behave differently in this case. In any case, if NickServ requires that you identify after setting your nick, it should let you know.)

For more info on how to use NickServ's rather impressive facilities, see [here](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1940).

Comment: All good. But the main issue I face is not being unable reclaim my old nick, but having to spam the channel with nick changes. Even if were to kill the old session with the `ghost` command, it is of not much use because there already is a nick change message in the channel.

Comment: You can do all the nick management stuff before you rejoin the channel, either by hand or before the `/join` commands in your login script. That cuts the channel spam down to a maximum of two messages (one when the old connection's killed, and the other when you rejoin); if you're losing your connection often enough that you need to reduce it further than that, you'll need to avoid being disconnected in the first place, which is where @allquixotic's suggestion of using a dedicated server would pay off.

Comment: Okay. I think XChat remembers me and messages `NickServ` itself with my password. So I've not had the need of a script. This is normal right?

Comment: I don't know about "normal", but it wouldn't surprise me at all to find an IRC client which is smart enough to talk with NickServ automatically on its user's behalf. ([My IRC client](http://www.emacswiki.org/ERC) apparently can do that too, but I never thought to look. Thanks for giving me the idea to go find out!)